# Not able to sign in using docker to canister.io - Authorization server did not include a token in the response

Tags: docker, bitbucket

Ok so I'm trying to make Bitbucket build a docker image using Bitbucket pipelines and I could sign in a week ago but now it doesn't work anymore.

And I'm using the same username and password, here it's a list of the commands I have tried and their output.

1. docker login cloud.canister.io:5000 --username $CANISTER_USERNAME --password $CANISTER_PASSWORD:

   - Error response from daemon: Get https://cloud.canister.io:5000/v2/: authorization server did not include a token in the response
2. docker login --username $CANISTER_USERNAME --password $CANISTER_PASSWORD cloud.canister.io:5000

   - Error response from daemon: Get https://cloud.canister.io:5000/v2/: authorization server did not include a token in the response
3. docker login cloud.canister.io:5000 --username $CANISTER_USERNAME

   - Password: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
   - Error saving credentials: error storing credentials - err: exit status 1, out: `Cannot autolaunch D-Bus without X11 $DISPLAY`
4. echo "$CANISTER_PASSWORD" | docker login cloud.canister.io:5000 --username $CANISTER_USERNAME --password-stdin

   - Error response from daemon: Get https://cloud.canister.io:5000/v2/: authorization server did not include a token in the response
5. echo "$CANISTER_PASSWORD" | docker login --username $CANISTER_USERNAME --password-stdin cloud.canister.io:5000

   - Error response from daemon: Get https://cloud.canister.io:5000/v2/: authorization server did not include a token in the response

I've also tried on a local machine and tried to do it without environment variables also tried to sign out and then try to sign in again but nothing works

Comment: Could you contact Canister to see if there is an issue? Also, if you want a free Docker registry, consider GitLab - it may be more reliable.

Comment: I just tried pulling images from canister.io with fresh login. It worked fine.

Comment: I got the exact same error when i tried to push a container with a tagname i did not first create manually in canister UI FYI. Worked fine after i created the repository (one kind off expect the repository to get created on-the-fly when pushing but not in canister it seems).

Could this be similar issue perhaps?

Comment: I got the same error when I tried to push my local images

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue when trying to push a new image to cloud.canister.io. It turned out I had not created the repository through the web frontend yet.

After creating the repo on cloud.canister.io I could successfully push my image up.

Answer (score 4):

for logging in this worked for me:

```
docker login --username=USERNAME cloud.canister.io:5000
```

Unfortunately, i am still getting this error message whenever i try to push my image.

Comment: same issue did you find any solution

Answer (score 4):

1. First you need to create an empty repo on  **cloud.canister.io**
   website with same name of the image you are trying to push.
2. Then you will be able to push to that repo.
3. Make sure you have authenticated the canister account using

```
sudo docker login --username=<username> cloud.canister.io:5000
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me. Hopefully this will be helpful to somebody.

I built an image from a custom Dockerfile. I am running Docker Desktop on my Win11.

```
docker build -t <image>:<tag> .
```

I logged into canister.io.

```
docker login --username=<username> --password=<username> cloud.canister.io:5000
```

I tagged the build.

```
docker tag <image>:<tag> cloud.canister.io:5000/<canister-namespace>/<canister-repo>
```

I pushed the image to canister.

```
docker push cloud.canister.io:5000/<canister-namespace>/<canister-repo>
```

I deleted the image from my Docker Desktop and I tried to pull it from canister.

```
docker pull cloud.canister.io:5000/<canister-namespace>/<canister-repo>
```

Here's an examples with some dummy values:

```
docker build -t tc5:tc5tag .
docker login --username=myusername --password=mypassword cloud.canister.io:5000
docker tag tc5:tc5tag cloud.canister.io:5000/mynamespace/testrepo
docker push cloud.canister.io:5000/mynamespace/testrepo

# pull test
docker pull cloud.canister.io:5000/mynamespace/testrepo
```

Answer (score 0):

Been a while. But this helped me:

```bash
docker push (registryFullUrl)/$(dockerId)/$(imageName):$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(PATCH)
```

where:
$(registryFullUrl) = cloud.canister.io:5000

$(dockerId) = your canister id

$(imageName) = repository name

$(MAJOR).$(MINOR).$(PATCH) = version